# Show selected out of stock products in front

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection

**My all out of stock products are not shown at front.**

However, I would like to show **some selected out of stock products** in front.

I have a custom attribute called `show_out_of_stock_product` and is `yes/no` type.

I want to show only those out of stock products that are set `show_out_of_stock_product` to `yes`.

I have tried to do it through observer using `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event, but no luck so far.

My approach was:

```
    $layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
    $category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addCategoryFilter($category)
        ;

    $showOutCollection = $products
        ->addAttributeToFilter('out_stock_show_product', true)
        ;
```

Is it possible to add this `$showOutCollection` to the category with all other products.

Comment: Can you print $products and  $showOutCollection ? collections are got ot not??

Comment: Yes, I can confirm collection is set and can print them.